# Unable to find template "TemplateBundle:Menus:" in TemplateBundle:includes:side_menu.html.twig at line 1

Tags: php, symfony, menu, twig

i cant get my home page when i logging for the first time in my website

this is my home page twig

```
{#{% extends 'TemplateBundle::template_standard.html.twig' %}#}
{% extends 'TemplateBundle::template.html.twig' %}
{% block titre %}{% if app.session.get('module') is defined and app.session.get('module') != '' %}{{ app.session.get('module') }}{% endif %}{% if app.session.get('page') is defined and app.session.get('page') != '' %} | {{ app.session.get('page') }}{% endif %}{% endblock %}
{% block pageTitle %}{% if app.session.get('module') is defined and app.session.get('module') != '' %}{{ app.session.get('module') }}{% endif %}{% endblock %}
{% block pageSubTitle %}{% if app.session.get('page') is defined and app.session.get('page') != '' %}{{ app.session.get('page') }}{% endif %}{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">GENERAL</h3>

              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body chart-responsive">
<div id="donut-example" style="height: 300px;"></div>   </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.col (LEFT) -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Contrat par Risque</h3>

              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body chart-responsive">
            <div class="chart" id="chart" style="height: 300px;">
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
         </div>

            </div>

            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- LINE CHART -->
          <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Evolution des contrats</h3>

              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body chart-responsive">
<div id="line"></div>
</div></div>

</div>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.3.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
           Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut-example',
  data: [
    {label: "Produits", value: {{ produits }}},
    {label: "Police Groupe", value: {{ pg }}},
    {label: "utilisateurs", value: {{ client }}}
  ],
   backgroundColor: '#ccc',
  labelColor: '#060',
  colors: [
    '#FF7313',
    '#0DACE3',
    '#67C69D',

],
});

        </script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.3.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <div id="chart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
<script>
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'chart',
  data: [
    { date: 'education', value: {{ education }}, backgroundColor: '#ccc' },
    { date: 'retraite', value: {{ retraite }} },
    { date: 'deces', value: {{ deces }} },

  ],
  xkey: 'date',
  ykeys: ['value'],
  labels: ['nombre de contrats'],

});
</script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<script>
Morris.Line({
  element: 'line',
  data: [
  {% for toto in totos %}
{y:'{{toto.dateEffet }}' ,a:{{toto.montantTotal }}},
{% endfor %}
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a'],
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

and this is my menu in .../templatebundle/Menus

```
<aside class="main-sidebar">

    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">

        <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
        <div class="user-panel">
            <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ path('Home') }}">
                        <i class="menu-icon ion ion-ribbon-b bg-yellow-gradient"></i>
                        <div class="menu-info">
                            <h3 class="control-sidebar-subheading">{{ app.session.get('module') }}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
            <li><a href="{{ path('Home') }}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>Accueil</span></a></li>

            <li class="active" class="treeview">
                <a href="#"><i class="ion ion-settings"></i> <span>Menu</span> <i
                            class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li ><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-industry  "></i> Production<i
                                    class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i> </a>
                        <ul class="treeview-menu">
                            <li ><a href="{{ path('decesAccueil') }}"><i class="fa fa-umbrella"></i> Deces</a></li>
                            <li ><a   href="{{ path('ListeRetraiteAdhesions') }}"><i class="ion ion-ribbon-b"></i> Retraite</a></li>
                            <li ><a   href="{{ path('ListeEducationAdhesions') }}"><i class="ion ion-university"></i> Education</a></li>
                            <li ><a   href="{{ path('ListeRetraiteAdhesions') }}"><i class="ion ion-ios-pulse-strong"></i> Hospitalisation</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    {#<li><a href="#"><i class="ion ion-thumbsup"></i> Gestion des avenants</a></li>#}
                    <li><a href="{{ path('indexAdmin') }}"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Administration</a>
                    <li><a href="{{ path('parametrage') }}"><i class="ion ion-settings"></i> Parametrage</a>
                    <li><a href="{{ path('PersonnePhysique') }}"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Client/Sociétaire</a>
                    <li><a href="{{ path('ListeComptabilite') }}"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> Comptabilité</a>
                    <li><a href="{{ path('indexAdmin') }}"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i> Reporting</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul><!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
</aside>
```

how can i get my home page and charge the Home-menu.html.twig 
maybe i change the name of page 
from accueil.html.twig
to Home.html.twig

to get my home page after logg in??

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by adding a constructor to my controller

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $session = new Session();
        $session->set('module', 'Accueil');
        $session->set('page', '');
        $session->set('menu', 'Accueil-menu.html.twig');
    }
```